# How to merge two columns of different temporal datatypes in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, database, time-series, dolphindb

The datatype of the column date is DATE and the datatype of the column time is TIMe. I want to merge the two column and generate a new column whose datatype is TIMESTAMP. Which function should I use? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lsr8.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
timestamp(dateCol) + int(timeCol)
```

First convert the date column to timestamp type and then add the milliseconds within the day. DolphinDB represents the time object by milliseconds internally. So we directly convert the time column to integer.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. It will be helpful for future users as well.